# Compiling a django project to exe with Python 3.6 for Windows users

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller, py2exe

I have a django project I am working on (64-bit Ubunu with Python 3.6) and I need to compile it into an exe that Windows (32- and 64-bit) users can run and via `localhost` through their browser. For my project I need to import common packages such as `numpy`, `pandas`, `matplotlib`. Is this possible?

From what I've found so far, is that each of the tools I've come across does not work for one reason or another:

- [bbFreeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze): doesn't support Python 3
- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/): doesn't support importing packages (although heard it is very good for wrapping everything up into a *single* exe file
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/): Looked promising but only works up to Python 3.5 (unfortunate as I also found [this](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django) for Django -> exe)

Comment: I've found pyinstaller to be the best, do you really require python 3.6 ?

Comment: Others may need 3.6 in the future, but to be brutally honest: no I don't need 3.6 - **but** I am new to python/django and don't want my 'house of cards' collapsing. Is there a simple way to use 3.5 for this project without messing everything else up?

Comment: Except if you're using 3.6-only features (such as f-strings) then you can just get 3.5, redownload the packages in 3.5 and you can then use pyinstaller. If you have conda, you could make an environment specifically for 3.5 if you don't want python installations all over the place.